# Apache modules: C module vs mod_wsgi python module - Performance

Tags: c, performance, apache, module, mod-wsgi

A client of ours is asking us to implement a module in C in Apache webserver for performance reasons.  This module should handle RESTful uri's, access a database and return results in json format.  Many people here have recommended python mod_wsgi instead - but for simplicity of programming reasons.  Can anyone tell me if there is a significant difference in performance between the mod_wsgi python solution vs. the Apache + C.module.  Any anecdotes? Pointers to some study posted online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This module should handle RESTful uri's, access a database and return results in json format.

That sounds like the bulk of the work is I/O bound so you will not get much of a performance boost by using C.

Here is the strategy I would recommend.

1. Implement in Python
2. After getting it done, profile the code to see if there are any CPU bottlenecks.
3. Implement just the bottleneck portions in C.

Comment: Nice .. will keep that in mind. Could use all the ammo i can get to convince customer apache + C is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

G-WAN ANSI C scripts have shown that C scripts make a world of difference in terms of speed, see:

gwan.com

So using C might not be a bad idea after all...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the best of both worlds: maintainable code and speed, use Cython (http://cython.org). Cython compiles Python code (with optional type information) to C or C++, which in turn is compiled to system code.